# ForbiddenException: not allowed to access GET label

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, crnk

My

```
@Component
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
   {
      httpSecurity
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/labels**").permitAll()
               .anyRequest()
               .authenticated()
               .and()
               .csrf()
               .disable()
               .httpBasic();
   }
   @Override
   public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
   {
      auth.ldapAuthentication()
          .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
          .userSearchBase("ou=people")
          .userSearchFilter("uid={0}")
          .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
          .groupSearchFilter("uniqueMember={0}")
          .contextSource()
          .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=concretepage,dc=com")
          .and()
          .passwordCompare()
          .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
          .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
   }

   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
      return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:${SPRING_BOOT_VERSION}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${SPRING_BOOT_VERSION}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:${SPRING_BOOT_VERSION}"

    api "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:${JAVAX_SERVLET_VERSION}"

    compileOnly 'io.crnk:crnk-gen-java' 
    annotationProcessor 'io.crnk:crnk-gen-java'

    gradle.beforeProject { Project project ->
        project.with {
            apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
            dependencyManagement {
                imports {
                    mavenBom "io.crnk:crnk-bom:${CRNK_VERSION}"
                }
            }
        }
    }


    implementation platform("io.crnk:crnk-bom:${CRNK_VERSION}")
    annotationProcessor platform("io.crnk:crnk-bom:${CRNK_VERSION}")

    implementation "io.crnk:crnk-setup-spring-boot2"
    implementation "io.crnk:crnk-home"

    implementation "io.crnk:crnk-security"
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.6.6'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:5.6.2'
    implementation 'com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk:4.0.14'

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${SPRING_BOOT_VERSION}")
}
```

The JsonApiEntity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonApiResource(type = "label", resourcePath = "labels", patchable = false, deletable = false, postable = false)
public class LabelJsonApiEntity
{
```

gralde version:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-03-31 15:25:29 UTC
Revision:     540473b8118064efcc264694cbcaa4b677f61041

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.2+8-86)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

The UI-error by GET `http://localhost:4503/labels/1234567890`:
`{"errors":[{"status":"403","title":"FORBIDDEN","detail":"not allowed to access GET label"}]}`

The log:

```
io.crnk.core.exception.ForbiddenException: not allowed to access GET label
    at io.crnk.core.engine.internal.repository.ResponseRepositoryAdapter$RepositoryRequestFilterChainImpl.checkResourceAccess(ResponseRepositoryAdapter.java:249)
    at io.crnk.core.engine.internal.repository.ResponseRepositoryAdapter$RepositoryRequestFilterChainImpl.doFilter(ResponseRepositoryAdapter.java:226)
    at io.crnk.core.engine.internal.repository.ResourceRepositoryAdapterImpl.findOne(ResourceRepositoryAdapterImpl.java:85)
    at io.crnk.core.engine.internal.dispatcher.controller.ResourceGetController.handleAsync(ResourceGetController.java:46)
    at io.crnk.core.engine.internal.dispatcher.controller.BaseController.handle(BaseController.java:56)
    at io.crnk.core.engine.internal.http.DocumentFilterChainImpl.doFilter(DocumentFilterChainImpl.java:28)
    at io.crnk.home.HomeModule$HomeDocumentFilter.filter(HomeModule.java:111)
    at io.crnk.core.engine.internal.http.DocumentFilterChainImpl.doFilter(DocumentFilterChainImpl.java:32)
    at io.crnk.core.engine.internal.http.JsonApiRequestProcessor.processAsync(JsonApiRequestProcessor.java:167)
    at io.crnk.core.engine.internal.http.JsonApiRequestProcessor.processAsync(JsonApiRequestProcessor.java:131)
    at io.crnk.core.engine.internal.http.HttpRequestDispatcherImpl.process(HttpRequestDispatcherImpl.java:73)
    at io.crnk.servlet.CrnkFilter.doFilter(CrnkFilter.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:181)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I tried different variants with same error:

```
.authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers( "/labels*").permitAll()
               .antMatchers( "/labels**").permitAll()
               .antMatchers( "/labels/*").permitAll()
               .antMatchers( "/labels/**").permitAll()
               .anyRequest()
               .authenticated()
```

Comment: you are trying to hit the url `http://localhost:4503/labels/1234567890`, whereas you have declared `/labels**`. It should be `/labels/**` in your `configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)` method.

Comment: changed but same error

Answer (score 0):

`crnk` need another component for the permissions.

```
@Component
public class SecurityConfigurer implements SecurityModuleConfigurer
{

   @Override
   public void configure(SecurityConfig.Builder config) {

      // no authorizations yet, just authentication
      // see link how to setup a full authorization server, PRs welcomed
      config.permitAll(Entity.class, ResourcePermission.ALL);
   }
}
```